# if-else latch SystemVerilog

Tags: if-statement, verilog

i was trying to make a floating point adder in SystemVerilog. When i saw the schematic generated i noticed the presence of a latch. The code is:

```
module ADDER (
    input   ieee_effloat  In1_ADD, In2_ADD,
    input   ieee_float    A_ADD,

    output  ieee_float    Out_ADD
    );

    logic [24:0] MantissaSum;                               //Can generate an overflow, expand at 25 bit

    always_comb
        begin
            MantissaSum = In1_ADD.Eff_Mantissa + In2_ADD.Eff_Mantissa;  //Sum the mantissas
            
            if(MantissaSum[24] == 1'b1)                        //If overflow
                begin
                    MantissaSum >>= 1;                      //Shift the mantissa of 1
                    Out_ADD.Exponent = A_ADD.Exponent + 1;  //<== Here is the latch (?)
                    Out_ADD.Mantissa = MantissaSum [22:0];  //Select the first 23 bit 
                end
            else
                begin
                    Out_ADD.Mantissa = MantissaSum [22:0];   //Select the first 23 bit
                end
        end

    assign Out_ADD = '{1'b0, Out_ADD.Exponent, Out_ADD.Mantissa};
    
endmodule
```

The types are defined:

```
`ifndef FPU_MACROFLAG
    `define FPU_MACROFLAG

    package FPU_DEFINITION;

        typedef struct packed {
            logic               Sign;
            logic        [7:0]  Exponent;
            logic        [22:0] Mantissa;
        } ieee_float;               //IEEE-753 floating point number rapresentation

        typedef struct packed {
            logic               Eff_Sign;
            logic        [7:0]  Eff_Exponent;
            logic        [23:0] Eff_Mantissa;
        } ieee_effloat;             //IEEE-753 floating point number rapresentation effective mantissa

    endpackage
    
    import FPU_DEFINITION::*;

`endif
```

I don't know why this happen, I even closed the if with the else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the latch is created in verilog is when you do not assign all outputs in all branches of an always block. In your situation:

```
    always_comb
        begin
```

you create a default value for `MantissaSum`. This way it is always assigned.

```
            MantissaSum = In1_ADD.Eff_Mantissa + In2_ADD.Eff_Mantissa;
```

now, when you shift it in one of the branches and do not do anything in the other one the previous statement will take care of it.

```
            if(MantissaSum[24] == 1'b1)                        //If overflow
                begin
                    MantissaSum >>= 1;                      //Shift the mantissa of 1
```

However, here is **you problem**. your `Out_ADD.Exponent` is only assigned in the *true* branch of the `if` statement. If ManticcaSum[24] is not 1, then its value is supposed to be the same as before. This is a latch behavior.

```
                    Out_ADD.Exponent = A_ADD.Exponent + 1;  //<== Here is the latch (?)
```

The rest is ok. `Out_ADD.Mantissa` is assigned in all branches.

```
                    Out_ADD.Mantissa = MantissaSum [22:0];  //Select the first 23 bit 
                end
            else
                begin
                    Out_ADD.Mantissa = MantissaSum [22:0];   //Select the first 23 bit
                end
        end
```

If this is what you want, you shold split this always block in two: one with always_comb, the second as always_latch, which takes care of the exponent. Or you should review your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies in the line `Out_ADD.Mantissa = MantissaSum [22:0];` because in the true and the false condition this statement is executed, I think the synthesized version of your code will infer a latch with the enable =  `!MantissaSum[24]` ( not 100% sure), I think the following change will keep the same logic and remove the latch.. just remove the line `Out_ADD.Mantissa = MantissaSum [22:0];` from both the true and the false conditions and instead outside of the `always_comb` block type the following `assign Out_ADD.Mantissa = MantissaSum [22:0];`, tell me if that solved your problem

Comment: Yes! Now it works, thank you so much. But i don't understand when I have to use assign and when always_comb.

Comment: @Gabbed You are welcome anytime my friend, in the true essence of things they are interchangeable, Mostly we use `always_comb` when there is some complex Combinational  logic we want to model but when it is simple we use the `assign` statement you can change the `assign` statement i just told you with `always_comb  Out_ADD.Mantissa = MantissaSum [22:0]; ` this should give you the same behavior